# Slant background color in <td> without slanting text

Tags: html, css, html-table, linear-gradients, skew

I am trying to slant a white background color within just the left < td > element without distorting the text within in.

```
<table style="border: solid 1px white; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td> TARGET <br /> THIS <br /> TD </td>

          <td>stuff <br /> stuff <br /> stuff</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above sample is my intended table. I put in the line breaks to mimic table rows so I would only have to apply the skew to one TD element instead of the whole first row and somehow align all their skewed background so they would flow smoothly between them.

I would like the result to show like...

[image]

The black background would come from the background applied to theparent div. I just need to paply the white background color to the left TD and then skew it allowing the parents black background color to show through.

THANKS!

Comment: applying a simple gradient on the first TD can do it I guess

Comment: duh! I completely looked over that possibility haha. Thanks